# ITN Callback from PayFast Returns Empty Body

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, express, payfast

I have a NodeJS Express app that returns a status 200 to PayFast on successful payment and logs the body of the response to the console. The problem is that the body is always empty and I cannot find any of the Payment's details in the response.

I tried to log the whole response in order to locate any data but was unsuccessful.

`app.post('/PayFastTest', (req, res) =>{ res.sendStatus(200); console.log(req.body) });`